# How to setup Azure-BitBucket-integration with repository's subfolders?

Tags: azure, deployment, bitbucket, publishing, azure-deployment

I have several cloud elements (websites, web roles, worker roles,...), each corresponds to different project.

I use single git repository for all of them, but each resides in its own sub-folder.

How can I set integration (with BitBucket) so that each project/cloud-element takes its code from certain sub-folder?

Alternatively, I can open repository for each project, but then I'll have problem sharing common code (like helper code) among the projects...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the directory to auto deploy from in your web app application's settings by adding a setting with a key of **Project** and the value **Path to Project**